# Setting EditText values on button press to a custom object's values

Tags: android

I'm working on an app that's main layout consists of a row of buttons on top of a LinearLayout which holds a column of EditTexts. I've created a Form object to hold all the values to be displayed in the Editexts, and there will be a Form object for every button in the row. Each button is clicked to change the form's data to show the values held in each Form object. I have the Form objects kept in a List called formList, so that I can access each one when the corresponding button is pressed.

When I click one of the buttons, I want the EditText values to change to a different set of values which correspond to that button.  But when I click these buttons, the previously entered values do not show up.

When I click Next Drink, it dynamically creates a button as well as a Form object, and clears the EditTexts so that it looks like a new form has been created for the new button. I should then be able to add strings to the EditTexts, and the strings should be stored in the Form object so that if I click that button again, the Form object will fill the EditTexts with the strings stored in that object.

So, if I click button 3 after having clicked button 2, it should set the text of each EditText to the values contained in the the third Form object, which contains strings for Name, Volume, Percentage, Price, and Quantity.

My problem is the values do not show up in the EditTexts after clicking a button. So if I click Button 3, the values from Form 3 don't show up. I've been at this for a long time and cannot figure out why, so I'd really appreciate any help. Here is the activity:

```
package com.example.DrinkApp;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.Editable;
import android.text.TextWatcher;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class MyActivity extends Activity {
/**
 * Called when the activity is first created.
 */




//view variables
final Button newDrink[] = new Button[100];
LinearLayout drinkSelectionContainer;
EditText name;
EditText vol;
EditText perc;
EditText pri;
AutoCompleteTextView quant;

//counters
int numOfDrinks = 0;
int selectedForm = 0;


//array to hold all Form objects.
List<Form> formList = new ArrayList<Form>();



@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);


    //get views
    drinkSelectionContainer = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.drinkSelectContainer);
    name = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etName);
    vol = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etVol);
    perc = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etPerc);
    pri = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etPrice);
    quant = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.etQuantity);
    Button saveDrink = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bSaveForm);

    Button nextDrink = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bNextDrink);
    Button crunkOut = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bCalc);

    ///////////////////////// next drink method
    addNewDrinkButton();



    name.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i2, int i3) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i2, int i3) {
            formAdd();

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {

//                mNames.add(selectedForm, name.getText().toString());
//                newDrink[selectedForm].setText(name.getText().toString());

        }
    });
    nextDrink.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            addNewDrinkButton();
        }

    });

}






//listener for drink select buttons. when button is clicked, it finds out which one it was,
//and then displays the correct values.
public View.OnClickListener drinkSelectListener = new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {

        selectedForm = v.getId();
        Form form = formList.get(selectedForm);
        Button v1 = (Button) findViewById(selectedForm);
        v1.setText(" " + selectedForm);
        // Do something depending on the value of the tag
        Log.v("My Logs:", "Select Drink " + selectedForm + " button pressed.");
        Log.v("My Logs:", "Drink " + selectedForm + " name: " + form.getName());


        formDisplay(form);


    }
};


private void addNewDrinkButton() {
    formClear();
    formAdd();
    numOfDrinks++;

    selectedForm = numOfDrinks;
    Log.v("My Logs:", "Next Drink button pressed.");


    newDrink[numOfDrinks] = new Button(getBaseContext());
    newDrink[numOfDrinks].setOnClickListener(drinkSelectListener);
    newDrink[numOfDrinks].setId(numOfDrinks);


    newDrink[numOfDrinks].setText("" + selectedForm);
    newDrink[numOfDrinks].setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

    // name.setText("Drink " + (numOfDrinks+1));

    drinkSelectionContainer.addView(newDrink[numOfDrinks]);



    //TODO: save form values, clear edit texts, and create new variables for edittexts.    
}


void formAdd(){

    Form tempForm = new Form();

    tempForm.setId(selectedForm);
    tempForm.setName(name.getText().toString());
    tempForm.setVolume(vol.getText().toString());
    tempForm.setPercentage(perc.getText().toString());
    tempForm.setPrice(pri.getText().toString());
    tempForm.setQuantity(quant.getText().toString());

    formList.add(selectedForm, tempForm);

}

void formDisplay(Form form){

    name.setText(form.getName());
    vol.setText(form.getVolume());
    perc.setText(form.getPercentage());
    pri.setText(form.getPrice());
    quant.setText(form.getQuantity());


}


void formClear(){

    name.setText("");
    vol.setText("");
    perc.setText("");
    pri.setText("");
    quant.setText("");


    }
}
```

![Here's the main layout. So if I click button 4, I want to have the EditTexts display the values
I'd entered the last time I'd clicked on it. It's really very simple.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1qiBs.png)

Comment: `com.example.DrinkApp` that seems to be the right app for Saturday night :-P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are calling formClear() before formAdd()?

Answer (score 0):

Setting EditText values on button press

> `edittext.setText("nexteditText");
>      edittext.requestfocus();`